# First Frame of SaveVideo playing longer, and last frame playing shortly

Tags: r, animation, ffmpeg

I'm using SaveVideo to create an animation based on different ggplots.
Here's what I am doing:

`saveVideo({for(i in 1:12){p <- ggplot()+...etc,video.name = "months.mp4")`

And these are my animation options:

`ani.options(interval=1.5,ani.width=1280,ani.dev = function(...){png(res=75*2.5,...)},ani.height=720, other.opts = '-analyzeduration 2M -probesize 1M')`

On the published video, the first frame lasts for like 5 seconds, then the other frames play normally, until the last frame which goes really quickly (less than 1 second). I have played around with different analyzeduration and probesize options with no results. Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual ffmpeg command being executed? Also show the ffmpeg log if you can.

Comment: The command is passed to the system so I believe is `-y -r <1/interval> -i <img.name>\%d.<ani.type> other.opts video.name`

Comment: Not very informative, unfortunately. If you show the **actual** command being executed by the code (no variables), and the complete log from the `ffmpeg` process I can give a suggestion. As it is, your question is too broad and not specific enough.